# Is it possible to use two different header section in Master Page in Kentico?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I have masterpage in kentico with normal layout and mobile device layout. I have two separate CSS files for both version of site, but I don't want to use them both on the header because they are overwriting each other. Second reason is that  I do not want to download all styles and js scripts from normal version on mobile page, because they are too big for mobile version (~1Mb). I do not use inheritance in masterpage but header is inherited in both versions of site and if I change it on device layout it is also changed on normal version. 
Is it possible to use two different header section in Master Page in Kentico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put following in the header section of your master page:

```
{% x=CurrentDevice.IsMobile; if (x) {"<link href=\"mobile.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />"} else {"<link href=\"normal.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />"} %}
```

And customize the condition and links to your css files.